# NetExtender Installation Shows Missing PPPD

Tags: raspberry-pi, pppd

I'm working on a raspberry pi and I'm trying to set up NetExtender on it. I've ensured that I have the java requirements, however, when I try to run the installer I get:

```
--- SonicWALL NetExtender 8.6.800 Installer ---
Checking library dependencies...
Checking pppd...
--------------------------- INSTALLATION FAILED ---------------------------

NetExtender requires a working installation of pppd. Please install pppd and try again.
```

I've been looking for ways to fix this but I really haven't found anything that has helped or I've just not understood what the forum was talking about. I'm new with this and not entirely sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem at first. After installing pptpd it worked for me. More information can be found in [this article](https://vpnreviewer.com/how-to-install-vpn-server-pptp-debian-ubuntu-linux-vps).